# How to add dependency to aar Android library?

Tags: android, dependencies, aar

could someone describe how to build aar file with it's own dependencies, and include all dependencies to the same aar file.

So I have the following dependencies in my aar file:

> compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

I don't want to push my users to import this module everytime they are importing my aar file, so, I want to include all code of volley (or only classes that I'm using in my aar file), but it is not clear how to do this.

I've tried 
https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar

but got the error:

> Project with path 'com.android.volley' could not be found in project
>   ':app'.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to include all dependencies to your aar file. So According to the [open source licenses](https://opensource.org/licenses) you can add their sources to your project.